# How can I apply Laplacian filter in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm just a beginner in this field. 
I want to apply Laplacian filter to the image that is imported from Keras. 
What should I do? If you have a good document, please share it.

```
model = Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same', input_shape=(28,28,1)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same'),
    layers.Flatten(),
    Dense(64,activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(10,activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()

input2 = Input(shape=(28,28,1))
Cv2D1=model.layers[0](input2)
MP1=model.layers[1](Cv2D1)
Cv2D2=model.layers[2](MP1)
MP2=model.layers[3](Cv2D2)
Cv2D3=model.layers[4](MP2)
flt=model.layers[5](Cv2D3)
D1=model.layers[6](flt)
D2=model.layers[7](D1)
model1 = Model(input2,D2)
```

This is part of the code I have.

Comment: What do you mean by " want to apply Laplacian filter to the image that is imported from Keras"? I believe you need to get to know Keras a bit more https://keras.io/

Comment: Also in your code you are just creating a neural network and I don't see what it has to do with applying Laplacian filter to image.